# Prestashop: SMARTY - force compilation / recompile when files are modified

Tags: css, smarty, prestashop, smarty2

I'm working on a Prestashop site and recently noticed about the SMARTY features (Menu: Advanced > Performance).
I realized that in order to show changes I made in the CSS, I must select one of the last two options (first one was selected by default).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8dOz.jpg) (I'm sorry the site is in Spanish)

1. Never recompile template files
2. Recompile templates when files are modified
3. Force compilation

My question is: when it comes to an online shop, which option should I select until I finish editing the code? What's the difference between both?
It may take me a couple weeks to finish the job and I don't want to mess anything up.

Thank you guys.

Comment: On a side note, sometimes, even when force compilation is selected, some templates are still cached. if the changes don't appear, it could be a good idea to delete the cache manually. inside cache/smarty/cache/ and cache/smarty/compile/ for v1.6 or inside app/cache/ for v1.7

Answer (score 0):

When you're starting to dev onto the shop, whether it's front or back, you may have to choose the option to recompile when files are modified. I'm always choosing this option because it allows me to develop or debug some files and the server keeps serving cache files to the visitors.

Also you may have to edit the file `defines.inc.php` file in the config folder in order to define the `_PS_MODE_DEV` to true, for example like this :

```
/* Debug only */
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_'))
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('217.128.240.59')))
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
else
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

Doing this so you'll be able to get some logs when you're updating something. Placing your IP into the array keeps everyone safe from seeing the logs (notices for example).

Answer (score 0):

In PS 1.6.
- Configure the SMARTY to "Recompile templates if the files have been updated" then deactivate the option "Smart cache for CSS"
- make the changes in your CSS files, 
- delete the folders mentioned *sadlyblue* in comment.
- and activate again the "Smart cache for CSS" SAVE to recompile theme.